# Android: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory return wrong path

Tags: android, environment

I use this code for save to sd card :

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"name.jpg");
```

This file save to **"Downloads/name.jpg"**

After save , i want delete this file by this code :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"name.jpg");
file.delete();
```

But return this path and not delete from SD card : **"storage/emulated/0/Downloads/name.jpg"**

Comment: the code `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` that is using the wrong path.

Comment: Can you give me correct code ?

Comment: I don't know what's `request` object. If you can tell me where it comes from. Maybe yes.

Comment: this code for download by download manager and save to download folder